# bar chart with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Here is my data structure:

```
data = {'2013': {1:25,2:81,3:15}, '2014': {1:28, 2:65, 3:75}, '2015': {1:78,2:91,3:86 }}
```

My x-axis is the number `[1,2,3]`

My y-axis is the quantity of each number. For example: In 2013, `1` is x axis while its quantity is `25`.

Print each individual graph for each year

I would like to graph a bar chart, which uses matplotlib with legend on it.

Answer (score 7):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {'2013': {1:25,2:81,3:15}, '2014': {1:28, 2:65, 3:75}, '2015': {1:78,2:91,3:86 }}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

I like pandas because it takes your data without having to do any manipulation to it and plot it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the keys of a dictionary via `dict.keys()` and the values via `dict.values()`

If you wanted to plot, say, the data for 2013 you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
x_13 = data['2013'].keys()
y_13 = data['2013'].values()
pl.bar(x_13, y_13, label = '2013')
pl.legend()
```

That should do the trick. More elegantly, do can simply do:

```
year = '2013'
pl.bar(data[year].keys(), data[year].values(), label=year)
```

which woud allow you to loop it:

```
for year in ['2013','2014','2015']:
    pl.bar(data[year].keys(), data[year].values(), label=year)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways.

### The *Functional* way using [bar()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html):

```
data = {'2013': {1: 25, 2: 81, 3: 15}, '2014': {1: 28, 2: 65, 3: 75}, '2015': {1: 78, 2: 91, 3: 86}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

X_axis = np.arange(len(df))

plt.bar(X_axis - 0.1,height=df["2013"], label='2013',width=.1)
plt.bar(X_axis, height=df["2014"], label='2014',width=.1)
plt.bar(X_axis + 0.1, height=df["2015"], label='2015',width=.1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

More info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plotting-multiple-bar-charts-using-matplotlib-in-python/).

[image]

### The *Object-Oriented* way using [figure()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html):

```
data = {'2013': {1: 25, 2: 81, 3: 15}, '2014': {1: 28, 2: 65, 3: 75}, '2015': {1: 78, 2: 91, 3: 86}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig= plt.figure()

axes = fig.add_axes([.1,.1,.8,.8])

X_axis = np.arange(len(df))
axes.bar(X_axis -.25,df["2013"], color ='b', width=.25)
axes.bar(X_axis,df["2014"], color ='r', width=.25)
axes.bar(X_axis +.25,df["2015"], color ='g', width=.25)
```

[image]