# Python pandas iterate over specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I'm trying to make a bar chart of some specific columns of a dataset:

```
for kolom_naam in attributen_dataset:
if kolom_naam in categorische_var:
    print(kolom_naam)
    attributen_dataset.kolom_naam.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

where attributen_dataset is a large dataframe and categorische_var is a list containing names of columns in the attributen_dataset (the names in the list are strings)

i don't know the correct syntax for selecten a column using the 'kolom_naam' iteration var. 
The rest works because the print(kolom_naam) does exactly what it says.

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: you really don't need to iterate. if you share your sample data, there are ways to do a bar plot without iterating.

Comment: Ok thanks. but i want to do it this way, it seems intuitive to me. Or is it not possible this way?

Comment: i know what you mean. I sometimes also try to loop through to see the data I am plotting. It is not necessary, if you have dataframe `df`: `df.plot(kind='bar')` give you a bar chart.

Comment: see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956199/bar-chart-with-matplotlib

Comment: Okay, but i want only bar charts of specific columns, more specifically the ones whose names are in the list 'categorische_var'.

Comment: Try this: `df_new = df[categorische_var]` and then   `df_new.plot(kind="bar")`

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to do a full mockup using random values. Here I have used `categorische_var` to filter for column `A` and `C`.

Let me know if it works for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.random.rand(10,4)
y[:,0]= np.arange(10)



attributen_dataset = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["X", "A", "B", "C"])

categorische_var=['A', 'C']


for kolom_naam in attributen_dataset:
    if kolom_naam in categorische_var:
        print(kolom_naam)
        #attributen_dataset.kolom_naam.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')

df_new = attributen_dataset[categorische_var]        
df_new.plot(kind="bar")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. That's because I want seperate bar charts for each column. By the way, all these selected variables are categorical so I think I need the command value_counts(). The code you programmed does work this way for one individual column though. if I do this: df_new.column_name.value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')

Answer (score 0):

I have made another version based on comment you made in the old answer.  In this version, the bar charts are created in loop based on the columns in `categorische_var` : which is a filtered list of the original dataframe `attributen_dataset`. So you have separate bar charts created for each column you want.

Let me know if it works.

see the mockup below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

y = np.random.rand(10,4)
y[:,0]= np.arange(10)

attributen_dataset = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["X", "A", "B", "C"])

categorische_var=['A', 'C']
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,len(categorische_var), figsize=(12,3))
for kolom_naam in attributen_dataset:
    for i, kolom_naam in enumerate(categorische_var):
        attributen_dataset[kolom_naam].plot(ax=axes[i], kind='bar')
```